# Insert CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, prepared-statement

I´m inserting data with prepared statements.
How can I assign a variable to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and bind the value?

I have a database table with the columns "name, lastfed, lastdoc and id". The 2 columns called lastfed and lastdoc are of type timestamp. 
I have a function and once I run it I want lastfed and lastdoc to register the current date and time.

```
$lastfed = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
$lastdoc = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO test (`name`, `lastfed`, `lastdoc`, `id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

$query->bindValue(1, $name);
$query->bindValue(2, $lastfed);
$query->bindValue(3, $lastdoc);
$query->bindValue(4, $user);
```

Comment: Do you realize that mysql and PHP are two essentially *different* programs?

Comment: Well since the question was regarding addding data into the mysql databas I thought it was a relevant subject... @YourCommonSense

Comment: it is not about relevance, but rather irrelevance. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` you want to use is a **mysql** constant while you are trying to use whatever **PHP** constant.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean! Thanks! @YourCommonSense

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO test (`name`, `lastfed`, `lastdoc`, `id`) 
VALUES (?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?)
```

Or you set `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default to these columns DB wise. Then you can leave them from your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO test (`name`, `id`) 
VALUES (?, ?)
```

Comment: +2 the second approach is better for me

Comment: Thank you! I´ve already tried the first suggestion and didn´t work. The second suggestion doesn´t work for me either as I already have another column in the table which is called created and has current_timestamp on in. I need these 2 columns to change the time later on but when I run a specific function (start) they should register the current time...

Comment: I just tried the first suggestion again and removed bindValue 2 and 3 and changed 4 to 2 and it works! When I tried before I forgot to change the 4...! Thank you! I´ll mark this as solved!